# htacces no carga imágenes ni el css

Tags: php, web, .htaccess

Organicé mi **.htaccess** para esconder una URL de mi página y así volverla más amigable. La ruta de mi página es:

> mipagina.com/resources/pages/somos.php

y pretendo cambiarla a:

> mipagina.com/somos

Estoy utilizando **xampp** para hacer las pruebas locales y así poder subirla al hosting. El problema radica en lo siguiente, cuando hago el cambio utilizo este código:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Hide URL resources/pages/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ resources/pages/$1.php [NC,L]
```

pero resulta que no se me muestra el css ni tampoco las imágenes que están dentro de mi ruta ***resources/images/***

Implementé este código para así mostrar las imágenes que estaban anidadas, pero aparentemente no me funciona:

```
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Si alguien me pudiese ayudar con este problema quedaría muy agradecido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto sucede, porque al utilizar el url rewrite estamos obligados a realizar la carga de recursos utlizando la ruta completa.

Estoy 99.99% seguro que tu estilo css lo llamas de la siguiente manera.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='../css/miestilo.css'>
```

Con lo cual  no nos va a funcionar, Entonces debes llamarlo de la siguiente forma.

en caso de que estes trabajando en localhost.

```
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://localhost/miproyecto/css/miestilo.css'>
```

En caso de que este implementado ya, seria:

```
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://www.misitio.com/css/miestilo.css'>
```

Por esto es recomendable, que declares una variable que puedas acceder de forma global, tipo App::$webistePath, y para la carga de recursos podria ser por ejemplo.

```
<img src='<?php echo App::$webistePath?>/imagenes/laimagen.jpg' alt=''>
<link rel='stylesheet'href='<?php echo App::$webistePath?>/css/miestilo.css'>
```

De esta manera a la hora de llevarlo a un hosting, no tienes que editar todas las direcciones de nuevo, solo modificas la variable $websitePath con la ruta del dominio.

Comment: me funciono, ¡muchísimas gracias!